# Simple flutter animation issue

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I am trying to get this animation:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xUpzsHXow2DrtA_IYKLJQAAl0pS-Lvsm/view?usp=sharing
But I can't figure out how to fade the text at the top correctly. It should be semi transparent so that you can see the graph, and then become not transparent at all as a fixed header. How do I do this? This is an example of my code so far - It does most of the stuff I want, but the fixed app bar doesn't become semi-transparent to see the back. It'll make more sense when you watch the video of what I want - its really easy I think... Thank you SO much for helping me with this!

```
Scaffold(
      body: NestedScrollView(
          headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
            return <Widget>[
              SliverAppBar(
                backgroundColor: AppColors("Dark").mainGrey,
                pinned: true,
                snap: true,
                floating: true,
                title: Row(children: [
                  const SizedBox(width: 10),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: size.width * .25,
                    height: size.height * .05,
                    child: const FittedBox(
                        child: Text('JustLift',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ))),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(width: 5),
                  Image.asset(
                    'assets/logos/logonotext.png',
                    width: size.height * .09,
                  ),
                  const Spacer(),
                ]),
              ),
            ];
          },
          body: CustomScrollView(slivers: [
            SliverAppBar(
                automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
                expandedHeight: size.height * .22,
                backgroundColor: AppColors("Dark").secondaryGrey,
                bottom: PreferredSize(
                    preferredSize: const Size.fromHeight(0),
                    child: Container(
                        width: size.width,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: AppColors("Dark").footerGrey,
                            borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                                topLeft: Radius.circular(10),
                                topRight: Radius.circular(10))),
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5))),
                flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
                  background: Container(
                      width: size.width,
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                          top: 10,
                          left: size.width * .07,
                          right: size.width * .07,
                          bottom: 10),
                      child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            Text('Welcome Back!',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Color.fromARGB(255, 234, 234, 234),
                                    fontSize: 21)),
                            Container(height: 100, width: 100 color: Colors.blue)
                          ])),
                )),
            SliverToBoxAdapter(
                child: Container(
                    color: AppColors("Dark").footerGrey,
                    child: Column(children: [
                      Center(
                          child: Container(
                              height: size.height * .3,
                              width: size.width * .95,
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 33, 33, 33),
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                              child: Column(children: const [
                                Text('Your Ranking',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: 23,
                                        color: Color.fromARGB(
                                            255, 182, 182, 182))),
                              ]))),
```